# How to reload page with modal after form submission

Tags: php, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog

I'm trying to show a bootstrap modal after submitting a form and getting the result from the database. The page has to reload and show the extra modal so that the user can try to log in again.

I've tried to reload the page and then echo the script

Here is what I have for now

```
<? php
if(condition)
  echo "<script>$('#modal').modal('show')</script>";
?>

...

<div class="modal fade" id="modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog"</div>
```

The page is either reloading without the modal, or a blank page. I expect it to load with the added modal.

Comment: Try adding the script part at the bottom of your page or wrapped in a $( document ).ready - function. Your modal might not be loaded when you try to open it

Comment: thank you this helped a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried tying the modal to a JS method, then calling the method from PHP?

```php
    <?php
        if($condition)
            echo "<script>showModal()</script>";
    ?>
```

```js
    function showModal() {
        $('#modal').modal('show');
    }
```

---

Edit:

You could try something like this:

```js
<script>
    $(function(){
        if (<?php echo $condition ?> === true) {
            $('#modal').modal('show');
        }
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Yes, I placed the showModal function at the html head and all it shows is a blank page after I submit the form.

Comment: Ah I thought of a better way to do this. I'll edit my original answer. My thought was that the javascript side of your code is being executed on pageLoad, not page ready. Moving it to a `$(function(){` call like above will execute the JS on document ready instead. (I just moved the PHP condition to the script, you don't have to mix PHP into JS like that).